# Prevent error reporting for variable variable in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have this code and get an error reported for the two "undefined" variables

```
$tables = [
            'foo',
            'bar',
            'baz'
        ];
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $$table = $this->setUpTables($table, $prefix);
}
$all = $this->getBaz($foo,$bar); // those two are reported as undefined
```

Is it possible to tell PhpStorm to not report this "error"?

EDIT:

```
/** @var foo $foo */
/** @var bar $bar */
$all = $this->getBaz($foo,$bar);
```

Comment: Use inline PHPDoc to declare them. No other way (except, maybe, suppressing warning for that line, which is just wrong approach overall). Another alternative requires editing your code to use real variables.

Comment: Do you mean like I edited in? @LazyOne, seems like the error is gone now.

Comment: Yes -- exactly what I meant.

Comment: Great, thank you! @LazyOne

Comment: Not sure how PHPstorm will see it, but an array?  `$result[$table] = $this->setUpTables($table, $prefix);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using simpler language features wins in this case, I think. PhpStorm should also have no trouble figuring out which variables are in scope.

```
$products        = $this->setUpTables('products', $prefix);
$excludeRules    = $this->setUpTables('excludeRules', $prefix);
$excludedSellers = $this->setUpTables('excludedSellers', $prefix);
$livePricing     = $this->setUpTables('livePricing', $prefix);

$all = $this->getProducts($products, $livePricing);
```

If PhpStorm thinks a variable is out of scope when it is not, you can add this declaration within the scope.

```
/** @var variableName */
```