# How to tell PhpStorm that some variable is defined

Tags: php, yii2, phpstorm

I am using Yii2 framework in PhpStorm.

My problem arises in views when I am using `$this->render` function to include another code of snippet inside my main file with some variables.

The code itself works perfectly I just have a problem with highlightings.

This is my code:

```php
<?php
echo $this->render('commentsBlock', [
            "comments" => $comments,
            'deleteURL' => $deleteURL,
            'editURL' => $editURL,
        ]);
?>
```

The code above renders *commentsBlock.php* and content of that target file is below:

[image]
[image]

As you can see the PhpStorm thinks that variables are not declared when they are defined.

I know that I need to add some comment which tells the IDE that vars do exist but what I tried did not work so far.

I did this:

[image]

But it is not highlighting.

Any ideas on how to write properly this comment section to trick IDE to highlight my variables?

Comment: Try to use a double asterisk (`/** @var array $comments */`). Or maybe `@global` annotation.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751330/phpstorm-warning-php-variable-might-not-have-been-defined  https://stackoverflow.com/q/42837882/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm not giving him solutions but asking to check something. Once Harry confirms this solves his problem I'll post it as a solution. I don't want to post anything I'm not certain about.

Comment: Your wording doesn't suggest that you are seeking a response.

Comment: It has been solved. It works with single asterisk comment like mentioned *Bizley* below. And works with double one too. @Haru `/** @var array $comments */` both are valid on my IDE

Comment: @harry do you necessarily need to declare the variable type? Does this work too? (I'm not at my computer to test) https://stackoverflow.com/a/31730971/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa Nope, I tested it and the type is like an optional parameter. Just `/* @var $myVar */` is totally enough. But `/* @var $myVar string */` is valid too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use vardoc like this:

```
/* @var $comments array */
```

This syntax is a bit different from phpdoc standard (notice the variable name and type switched places) but it's widely recognised by IDEs (including PhpStorm).

For more references see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798477/variable-type-hinting-in-netbeans-php) for example.

Comment: Please check this out : https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#824-var

Comment: Isn't that `/** @var $comments array */` instead?